# Remove morph relationship of 2 models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to remove the relationship between two models in a one-to-one polymorphic relationship.
In the example below, I want both comment and post to exist but just remove the relationship netween them. That is I want to set commentable_id and commentable_type to null.

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

relationship:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}

class Video extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

#### For one post or video:

```php
Post::find($id)->comments()->update(['commentable_id' => null, 'commentable_type' => null]);

Video::find($id)->comments()->update(['commentable_id' => null, 'commentable_type' => null]);
```

#### For more posts or videos:

```php
Comment::whereIn('commentable_id', $id_array)
       ->where('commentable_type', 'App\Post')
       ->update(['commentable_id' => null, 'commentable_type' => null]);

Comment::whereIn('commentable_id', $id_array)
       ->where('commentable_type', 'App\Video')
       ->update(['commentable_id' => null, 'commentable_type' => null]);
```

*PS: Be sure you have set your commentable_id to be nullable.*

However, my suggestion is try to use [soft-deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting) instead of setting nullable value.

So that you can still find those comments which model belongs to.

#### For soft-deleting comments:

```php
Post::find($id)->comments()->delete();
Video::find($id)->comments()->delete();
```